# How to embed lua in c++ via SWIG

Tags: c++, lua, swig

Currently I have a set of SWIG wrappers for my classes and it all builds. I can create a lua virtual machine and load my wrappers, but at that point I'm flummoxed. Googling tells me how to shove put c++ in lua in swig, but not how to put lua in c++.

Really all I want to do is manage to instantiate a lua object and pass it my main game engine object pointer, from there I can manage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Programming in Lua book, it has a section on the [Lua C API](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pcall).

For calling Lua functions use [lua_pcall](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pcall), which is equivalent to [lua_call](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_call) (that has a short example) except it will catch Lua runtime errors.

You must have already loaded and run the script once (using eg. [luaL_dofile](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_dofile)) since the first step is for the script to define the functions for you to call. When it returns, you can access the script-defined functions with [lua_getglobal](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_getglobal).

Comment: From personal experience with SWIG + Lua, I would *highly recommend* writing your own C++->lua calls. There are a few libraries out there and I had a disaster case trying to pair SWIG with Luabind (SWIG for Lua->C++, and luabind for C++->Lua) - just keep it simple. Binding is really the hard part. However, you'll run into more issues by trying to abstract away calls to Lua as well.