# OpenSouce C/C++ Math expression parser Library

Tags: c++, math

I'm searching for a good open source Math Library which can do things like:

- Parse math. expressions "1+1*(3/5)"
- Integration

Does anybody know something like this?

Comment: expression parsing and integration are rather different, depending on how complex the integration you need

Comment: Some free Java and C++ implementations of the Shunting Yard Algorithm for converting expressions to Reverse Polish Notation and then evaluating these can be found here:              http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/a-mathematical-expression-parser-in-java-and-cpp/

Comment: example parsing of math expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32853177

Answer (score 7):

There's also [GNU libmatheval](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmatheval/), which does evaluation and differentiation. Integration is a much [harder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) problem, even for innocent-looking integrands.

Comment: +1, I'd not come across that before and it looks quite interesting.

Answer (score 5):

[Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) can do this and can be called from [within a C++ program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave#C.2B.2B_Integration).
 You can even call C++ code from octave easily using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Octave.html) to generate the interface.

Answer (score 3):

I've always used [muParser](http://muparser.sourceforge.net/), written in C++, for parsing. You're not going to get a library which can do integration; simply too difficult without a serious heavyweight library. Open source symbolic integrators like Maxima, Octave, etc. exist, but they are hard to interface with, and that functionality can't easily be separated from the rest of the project.

Answer (score 2):

Try my [ae](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#ae) library, which is based on Lua. See also [Evaluating Mathematical Expressions using Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156572/evaluating-mathematical-expressions-using-lua)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to embed an interpreted language in your app and use that langauge's maths parser.

LUA is becoming popular for this - see [How to embed lua in c++ via SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556309/how-to-embed-lua-in-c-via-swig)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar programing need where I used the [Shunting yard algorithm](http://en.literateprograms.org/Shunting_yard_algorithm_%28C%29?oldid=12454). 
Useful for parsing [infix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) like you have.

Answer (score 0):

There's [MathPresso](https://bitbucket.org/tartakynov/mathpresso/wiki/Home) library which is parser and also JIT compiler of math expressions, I use it when the performance is important.

Some tests: 
evaluating expression "x / y + (x * x * y + 18.243 * y) / z" - where the variables are double precision floating point numbers.

- C++ function: 144.1 millions of evaluations per second
- MathPresso: 133.8 millions of evaluations per second