# Parse multi-stacks to find how to properly set up an equation

Tags: c++, stack

It has been awhile since I have used C++ I was wondering if anyone can give me a good way on how to create two stacks and then grab a user input such as: 1+6/3 and parse though this input to put the numbers in a 'number stack' and the operators in an 'operator stack', then make a priority list to make sure the proper operators are used in the equation first so the answer comes to 3.  Any tips would be very much appreciated, I never use stacks.

Comment: Write a recursive descent parser: http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Recursive_descent_parsing#C

Comment: This should work perfect, thank you that wasn't even on my mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser
- [Evaluating arithmetic expressions from string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329406/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-in-c)
- [What is the best way to evaluate mathematical expressions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115872/what-is-the-best-way-to-evaluate-mathematical-expression-in-c)