# Parsing expression with complex numbes

Tags: c++, char

I want to transform a C-string to complex expression and simplify it.

For example for the string:

```
(3+2i)² + 6-i-3+2i
```

output should be: `8+13i`;

Comment: The idea is great, but what is the question?

Comment: @soon, the code should be given. :)

Comment: The idea is to code your idea :)

Comment: You mean string expression?

Comment: I don't have a code because i don't have an idea how to solve this. And the question is: how can i transform a char to a complex expression. I need only an idea. I don't know how to implement the operations and also how to separe a complex number from this expression.

Comment: Need some help with what exactly? Asking a question fit for the SO format, or one that's code related?

Comment: @enhzflep I don't have a code because i don't know where to start. This problem is confusing for me too. Basicaly I have to transform a char to a complex expression then i have to solve that expression.

Comment: @MarounMaroun i can't code my idea because i don't know from where i can start.

Comment: @StelianB., So, if you have a question - ask it. You can edit your post with pressing button `edit`. Please, make the question understandable to other SO users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to evaluate mathematical expression in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115872/what-is-the-best-way-to-evaluate-mathematical-expression-in-c)

Comment: @soon you men to post the code, but till now i don't have one.

Comment: @soon i have to transform a char ((3+2i)2 + 6-i-3+2i) to a complex numbers expression and then to evaluate it.

Comment: @StelianB. - okay, gotcha. I'd start googling for "c/c++ complex expression evaluator" or "c/c++ evaluate complex expression". The bulk of the problem will be in extracting the individual terms that need to be evaluated. You've got brackets to deal with, the `2` superscript (squared operator), then, finally - you get to add/multiply/subtract the complex numbers. Oddly enough, dealing with complex numbers is the least complex part of this question, methinks.

Comment: Your string already is a complex expression. What you need is a tool to parse it or evaluate it. Your deadline isn't anybody else's problem.

Comment: @EJP I am not allowed to use any tool or complicated things to evaluate this string, just only basic things.

Comment: @StelianB. You are going to use something at least as complex as an expression parser, whether you write it yourself or get it elsewhere. There is nothing 'basic' about this problem.

Answer (score 11):

You need a library that can parse mathematical expressions. Either write your own or take one of the existing ones (like [ExprTk](http://partow.net/programming/exprtk/)).