# Multiple operation arithmetic

Tags: c, evaluation, expression-evaluation

I just completed a beginners C programming course and I thought handling arithmetic would be a great first project! I had no problem figuring out how to do basic single operation arithmetic.

I ahieved what I initially desired but now I'm curious if it's possible with(out) some library, to handle multiple operators in precedence, e.g. `5+2*3`. Of course `2*3` should be evaluated and then 5 added to the product. If parenthesis wrap an equation it should be handled first

So to clarify I want to read stdin and parse a literal string, then handle any arithmetic by *PEMDAS* precedence. I have tried many different queries to find something like what I'm looking for - I'm sure someone has done it, I just can't find it!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm

Comment: Use a stack to push and pop operators and operands

Comment: Here is a tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dsa_using_c/dsa_using_c_parsing_expressions.htm  And then this less tutorial-ish version: https://cp-algorithms.com/string/expression_parsing.html  And an actual library that does it: https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr

Comment: duplicates: [How to evaluate a mathematical expression using strings and arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26574098/995714), [Is there a way to run C code that's stored in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66094374/995714), [What is the best way to evaluate mathematical expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5115872/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to run C code that's stored in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66094374/is-there-a-way-to-run-c-code-thats-stored-in-a-string)

Comment: You're looking at ASTs here. [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

Comment: Or just binary expression trees.

Comment: arithmetic doesn't really require a full fledged grammar, so lexical scanner and semantics can be bypassed/skipped. A stack would work well too, however for it to work - you'd need to transform your arithmetic expression from [infix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) to [prefix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) as that is much more stack-friendly. However, i might be wrong on this, but i believe transforming it from infix to prefix would require it to be parsed into an AST regardless.

Comment: @Lundin yes, or that. arithmetic doesn't really have operations that work on more than two operands. :) i was merely suggesting a direction to be considered.

Comment: It's easy to write a simple [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) that evaluates as it goes.  See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472680#66104290).

Comment: I am working on implementing a push and pop stack currently, as suggested by @stark. I looked up infix to postfix in C after reading about the shunting yard algorithim linked initally. Trying to implement it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I managed to write my own infix to postfix equation. The evaluation part.. Not so much!

I did end up with a functional solution from @[Jerry Jeremiah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193968/jerry-jeremiah)'s answer. Using the [TinyExpr](https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr) library, I was able to include their header, compile with their .c program and upon calling `te_interp`, handle arithmetic better than I could hope to!