# Dynamically Allocating an Array from a Polynomial Function String

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

So I have a polynomial addition problem like the one below:

```
(1*x+2*x^3-1*x+7)+(1+1*x^2-1*x+1*x^4)
```

I need to figure out how to extract the numbers for the coefficients and exponents and enter them into a dynamically allocated 2D array (from here I can sort them and add them together before outputting the answer).

I am pretty lost on how to do this because the polynomials can be in any order of degrees and include any amount of terms.  I can dynamically allocate them after I extract all of the numbers.  The part I need help on is:

- Extracting all of the numbers
- Differentiating between them to see if it is a coefficient or an exponent
- Allowing this to happen for any number of terms

If anyone could answer this or at least point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: What you are looking for is called `std::vector` and either a term class with two members or a `std::pair`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem looks like its parsing and evaluation.

- Step1: You need to parse the string assuming an infix expression, so
  that you can pull out the coefficient
- Step2: push those coefficients into a **vector/deque** etc to perform the
  polynomial calculation.

Here are some good examples:

[Evaluating arithmetic expressions from string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329406/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-from-string-in-c)

[What is the best way to evaluate mathematical expressions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115872/what-is-the-best-way-to-evaluate-mathematical-expressions-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

To extract coefficients from a string you need to create a parser. You can use special library like [boost.spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/), you can use special tool which builds parsers like [Flex](https://www.gnu.org/software/flex/), or you can make your own manually using regular expressions or not.

To store coeficients you can use `std::vector<int>` using indexes as power of x, so for 1*x+2*x^3-1*x+7 your vector would have data:

```
{ 7, -1, 0, 2 } // 7*x^0 + -1*x^1 + 0*x^2 + 2*x^3
```

then you do not need to sort them to add coefficients. To store all polynoms you would use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` accordingly.