# std::stod throw invalid_argument exception

Tags: c++, std

I make some simple program, that calculate expression in `std::string` format.
But `std::stod` is throwing `invalid_argument` exception. Here is the code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string expr = "(0.5 * 2.0000)";
    std::string::size_type st;
    double result = std::stod(expr, &st);
    std::cout << "Result of expression evaluation: " << result << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Maybe I shoudln't use `std::stod`, and use something else?

I tried c++ 14/17/20 - same exception is thrown

Comment: [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) is for converting a single value, not for evaluating an expresion in a string.

Comment: @wohlstad well, that explains everything. Do you know anything that could evaluate expression?

Comment: I am not familiar with such a standard function, but there are some libraries that can help. See e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115872/what-is-the-best-way-to-evaluate-mathematical-expressions-in-c.

Comment: @wohlstad I see. I guess then, this question can be closed. Thank you for clarification

Comment: Give `std::from_chars` in `<charconv>` a try.

Comment: @Red.Wave I believe `std::from_chars` does not supports evaluation of mathematical expressions.

Comment: @wohlstad Mathematical expressions have no std string support either way. The point is that `std::from_chars` returns an error code instead of throwing an exception. Moreover, you can lift off from the position where previous call failed. Expression parsing is a full project of its own.

Comment: Sure, but since the OP specifically needed to evaluate an expression, I don't think using `std::from_chars` will help them in this case (although I agree it is a good utility for parsing single values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression "(0.5 * 2.0000)" is not a valid floating-point number format, but rather a mathematical expression. Therefore, attempting to convert it directly using `std::stod` will result in an invalid_argument exception because  `std::stod` cannot parse the input string as a valid floating-point number.
If you want to evaluate mathematical expressions you'll need to use a library that can parse and evaluate mathematical expressions, such as `exprtk`. Below is a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "exprtk.hpp"
int main()
{
    typedef exprtk::expression<double> expression_t;
    typedef exprtk::parser<double> parser_t;

    std::string expr_string = "(0.5 * 2.0000)";
    expression_t expr;

    parser_t parser;
    parser.compile(expr_string, expr);

    double result = expr.value();
    std::cout << "Result of expression evaluation: " << result << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```