# Using boost::lexical_cast with arithmetic expressions

Tags: c++, boost

I have an input file (ASCII) with arithmetics, e.g.
    `TEST;0.0;0.0+0.1;0.0+0.2`

I can read the string and split it accordingly, so I already have elements of `std::string`. Now I wanted to use `boost::lexical_cast<double>` to store it in a double, comparable to an expression like:

```
double d = boost::lexical_cast<double>("0.0+0.1");
```

However, Boost throws

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >'
what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
```

Is there a good way to go, maybe without `sscanf`? (If `sscanf` would be capable of doing this at all...)

TIA

Comment: wait, you expect lexical_cast to calculate 0.0+0.1 for you?

Comment: How complicated are you expressions?  Arbitrary-depth nesting with parentheses?  What operators do you want implemented?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes, I thought so. Too much to ask?

Comment: You're going to need to parse out the result on your own.  Perhaps using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation and a custom parser.

Comment: @robert: Just division and addition, coordinates like 50 + 10./60. + 20./3600.

Comment: I'm suggesting that he parses his infix notation into RPN, then does the calculations on his own.

Comment: `lexical_cast` converts _values_ from one type to another, via a string representation, it's not an arithmetic expression parser, so yes, way too much to ask. (All it does is write the source value to a `stringstream` then read it out again as the target type, and iostreams can't interpret arithmetic expressions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::lexical_cast` is not a parser/calculator. You could use [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) to do this. There's an [O'Reilley example](http://www.oreillynet.com/network/2003/05/06/examples/calculatorexample.html) on how to implement such a calculator, but as you can see it's not straight-forward.

Questions [OpenSouce C/C++ Math expression parser Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4071456/167251) and [Evaluating arithmetic expressions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329406/167251) might be good starting points if you want to implement a simple parser.

Comment: Thank you. Seems I was a little to demanding and naive. However, to much effort for little benefit... I changed the ASCII values by hand. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be splitting the strings again, if there's an arithmetic operator in the string, do the cast for both substrings and then do the arithemtic operation.

I don't think boost::lexical_cast or anything similar does this or is intended to do this.