# What is the most standard mathematics notation that could easily parse and compute in any programming language?

Tags: math

I want to store mathematics formula as string in database and load it to inject and compute in any programming language

It should be easy notation that could write by hand and should support at least basic arithmetic operation include pow and sqrt and log in any base

I wish there would be standard format for math notation that any language could agree upon. Is there anything like that? Is there a most popular notation format?

Comment: This question would be probably more suited to the [**Math StackExchange**](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: MathML, but it's almost more trouble than it's worth. For one, while all languages can parse it (it is XML), few if any languages can _execute_ it.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Main point here is notation for the programming language

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071456/opensouce-c-c-math-expression-parser-library

Answer (score 2):

Many shell languages can calculate using elementary mathematical formulae, represented as strings. For example, the [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) shell in Linux contains `bc` - "An arbitrary precision calculator language":

```
hekto@ubuntu:~$ bc --version
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

hekto@ubuntu:~$ echo '2+2' | bc
4

hekto@ubuntu:~$ echo 'sqrt(2)' | bc -l
1.41421356237309504880
```

So, if your programming language of choice can communicate with shell, and this shell can calculate, then your problem is solved.

Comment: Is "communication with shell" work in android and ios?

Comment: I guess - yes, they are flavors of Linux anyway